# AngularJS {{ val | number:1 }} not rounding to 1 decimal place

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, decimal, rounding

```
<p> <b>{{ x.title }} </b>  Rating:{{ x.rating | number:1}}</p>
```

The above code is what I'm using. It is getting the value correctly because it is showing an unrounded number (e.g. 3.333333333) so I know the value is passed correctly. Why won't the number:# filter work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. CLEAR YOUR CACHE KIDS - It was working but hadn't reloaded my index.html file.